# SCDF - Header Enricher Processor with multiple headers

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I've deployed spring-cloud-dataflow with Docker. These are the used containers:

- springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local:1.7.1.RELEASE
- wurstmeister/zookeeper
- wurstmeister/kafka:1.1.0

[other containers not involved in the issue ...]

**Documentation consulted:**

[Spring Cloud Data Flow Reference Guide - 1.7.1.RELEASE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.7.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/)

[Header Enricher Processor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/Celsius.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-stream-modules-header-enricher-processor)

> I am trying to use the header-enricher processor to add multiple headers, but i can only add one header.
>
> With the following example:

```
time | header-enricher --headers="foo='bar' \n baz='qux'" --overwrite=true | log --expression=headers
```

> Also add this propertie to the deployment

```
app.*.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers=foo,baz
```

> The header-enricher log is throwing next error at start.
>
> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.transformer.support.ExpressionEvaluatingHeaderValueMessageProcessor]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.header.enricher.processor.HeaderEnricherProcessorConfiguration' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'processor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'baz'

**EDIT:** I am currently using these two ways to define the stream.

1. **SCDF Dashboard**: Throwing next error

[image: SCDF Dashboard]

2. **SCDF Shell spring-cloud-dataflow-shell-1.7.2.RELEASE** Throwing next error
   and it seems that he does not accept the character \

[Shell Quotes and Escaping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.7.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#dsl-quotes-escaping)

[image: SCDF Shell]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your expression. You need to remove the double quotes

```
 --headers=foo='bar' \n baz='qux'
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I have tried to define the stream removing the double quotes but it's still not working.